# Remove divider after last item while using ngFor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using this code to show a number of locations:

```
<div class="location" *ngFor="let item of location_array">
   {{item}} <hr>
</div>
```

which results in all the locations, separated by an horizontal rule. How can I edit this to get the exact same result, but without the last horizontal rule?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `last` provided by the `*ngFor` along with `*ngIf` on your `<hr>`:

```
<div class="location" *ngFor="let item of location_array; let lastItem = last;">
   {{item}} <hr *ngIf="!lastItem">
</div>
```

Here is a [**StackBlitz Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-my6ani?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

Comment: I don't think it is working in the way it should work. I see <hr/> getting for all items.

Comment: I expected a more complex way to do it, but stack-overflow never disappoints.

Answer (score 4):

In the current angular version (11) the syntax changed to the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of location_array; last as isLast">
    {{ item }} <hr *ngIf="!isLast">
</div>
```

See https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables