# Angular - How to add dividers in between select options using ngFor?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm using a ngFor to populate my select with options.

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor='let item of items; let i = index, [value]='item.name',)> {{ item.label }} </option>
</select>
```

I want to add a divider after a certain option. So something like this

```
Item1
Item 2
-- Divider --
Item 3
```

I've gotten as far as displaying the divider by using the index

```
<option *ngFor='let item of items; let i = index, [value]='item.name',)> {{ item.label }} {{ i == 2 ? '----' : ''}}</option>
```

But I can't seem to get it to it's own line.
Any tips on how this can be done? Also any advice on how to have a better looking divider than --- would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove divider after last item while using ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324884/remove-divider-after-last-item-while-using-ngfor)

Comment: While your question is slightly different, I think the linked answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49324923/10747134 is what you are looking for.
Basically, you need to have another "block" aside from your option, otherwise the divider will be included in your option. A recommendation would be to follow that link, but instead of using a div use an <ng-container> tag. That way, the option code can remain the option code, and below that with another block you can have your divider code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `*ngFor` on an `<ng-container>` element. Then you can add multiple child elements for each array item.

Example:

```
<select>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items;">
    <option [value]="item.value">{{item.name}}</option>
    <option *ngIf="item.name === 'foobar'" disabled="disabled">----</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my problem.